# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, swt, communication, jmtp

I am working on Java SWT for windows application.

In this project I need to check whether a phone device is connected to system or not. For this I used JMTP.jar

and

org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86-3.5.1.jar

My code is

```
PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
manager.refreshDeviceList();
PortableDevice device[] = manager.getDevices();
```

But I am getting this error while creating object for PortableDeviceManager.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: probleem met de com
at jmtp.PortableDeviceManagerImplWin32.<init>(PortableDeviceManagerImplWin32.java:52)
at jmtp.PortableDeviceManager.<init>(PortableDeviceManager.java:34)
at FindFile.main(FindFile.java:96)
```

System configurations: Windows xp 32 bit and JDK 1.7 32 bit.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: If anyone is wondering: [Here](https://code.google.com/p/jmtp/source/browse/trunk/java/src/jmtp/PortableDeviceManagerImplWin32.java?r=5) is the source of the class throwing the `Exception`.